# How to load large multi file parquet files for tensorflow/pytorch

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, pytorch, parquet

I am trying to load a few parquet files from a directory into Python for tensorflow/pytorch.

The files are too large to be loaded through the pyarrow.parquet functions

```
import pyarrow.parquet as pq
dataset = pq.ParquetDataset('dir')
table = dataset.read()
```

This gives `out of memory error`.

I have also tried using `petastorm`, but that doesn't work for `make_reader()` because it isn't of the `petastorm` type.

```
with make_batch_reader('dir') as reader:
  dataset = make_petastorm_dataset(reader)
```

When I used the `make_batch_reader()` and then the `make_petastorm_dataset(reader)`, it again gave an `zip not iterable error` or something along those lines.

I am not sure how to load the file into Python for ML training. 
Some quick help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks
Zash

Answer (score 2):

For `pyarrow`, you can list the directory with Python, iterate over `*.parquet` files, open each one as `pq.ParquetFile`, and read it [one row group at a time](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.parquet.ParquetFile.html#pyarrow.parquet.ParquetFile). This will alleviate the memory pressure, but won't be super fast without parallelization.

For `petastorm`, you are right to use `make_batch_reader()`. Indeed, the error messages are not always helpful; but you can inspect the stack trace and investigate where in [petastorm code](https://github.com/uber/petastorm/) it originates from.

Answer (score 2):

You can load entire data using dask using below code.
You can also load only chucks of data whenever needed by computing only those lines using the index. [Assuming you have different index].

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
from dask import delayed
from fastparquet import ParquetFile
import glob

@delayed
def load_chunk(pth):
    x = ParquetFile(pth).to_pandas()
    x = x.drop('[unwanted_columns_to_save_space]',axis=1)
    return x

files = glob.glob('./your_path/*.parquet')

ddf = dd.from_delayed([load_chunk(f) for f in files])
df = ddf.compute()
```